# Angularjs page reloading help inside controller

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i am trying to implement the login system in angularjs and php.

```
$scope.signForm = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.remember=true;
    $http.post('user/action/signin.php', $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.error = false;
                $scope.message = false;
                if (!data.success) {
                    $scope.error = data.error;
                    $scope.loading = false;

                } else {
                   $location.url('/userprofile.php'); //
                   $scope.loading = false;

                }
            });
};
```

i am checking for user login if success i need to load the userprofile.php. my userprofile.php page is different and not using angularui.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$window.location.href = '/userprofile.php'`

Comment: thanks.  but it is not working. i need to change something else ?

Comment: Sorry, typo! I meant $window.location.href = 'newUrl'.

Comment: not working. but solved by $window.location(); thanks a lot ;)